# Numpy reshape image to column major order is duplicating my picture

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, python-imaging-library, reshape, self-supervised-learning

For Self supervised learning purpose, I need to create a dataset composed of custom pictures.
I want to store my pictures in a bin file, as numpy array in the shape (3, 256, 256) in **column major order**.

My picture is of shape (256, 256, 3) as tiff file. I open it using `PIL.Image` as usual.

However, using the code below I obtain the following result :

```py
im = Image.open(file)
imarr = np.array(im)
imarr = imarr.reshape((3, 256, 256), order='F')

# for plotting
img = np.transpose(imarr, (1, 2, 0))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title('generate bin files')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As specification, using no `order` or other values as 'C' or 'A' result in  this kind of bugged pics:
[image]

How can I make it so `img` is only one of the 9 replicates of my picture ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out that I misused `np.reshape`.

Instead of

```py
imarr = imarr.reshape((3, 256, 256), order='F')
```

I use

```py
imarr = np.transpose(imarr, (2, 0, 1))
```

to have shape (3, 256, 256) and it works like a charm.